# SpringBoot 2.5.4 actuator/startup response's structure is different from the official

Tags: spring, spring-boot

## Pre Work

I want to track the various steps during my spring-boot application startup.
So i expose /actuator/startup endpoint.

i add necessary dependency to my POM

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
</dependency>
```

and my spring-boot version is 2.5.4

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

and i create a simple application with this implementation for my application

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        application.setApplicationStartup(new BufferingApplicationStartup(2048));
        application.run(args);
    }
```

when i query the startup actuator endpoint using curl:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/actuator/startup' -X POST
```

i get the response:

```
"springBootVersion": "2.5.4",
    "timeline": {
        "startTime": {
            "seconds": 1669706112,
            "nanos": 935000000
        },
        "events": [
            {
                "step": {
                    "name": "spring.boot.application.starting",
                    "id": 0,
                    "tags": [
                        {
                            "key": "mainApplicationClass",
                            "value": "co.hello.Application"
                        }
                    ],
                    "recorder": {},
                    "startTime": {
                        "seconds": 1669706112,
                        "nanos": 942000000
                    },
                    "ended": true
                },
                "endTime": {
                    "seconds": 1669706112,
                    "nanos": 954000000
                },
                "duration": {
                    "seconds": 0,
                    "nanos": 12000000
                }
            },
```

## Notice

the response's ***timeline.startTime***,***timeline.events.[].startTime***,***timeline.events.[].endTime*** and ***timeline.events.[].duration***  are different from the [official doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.4/actuator-api/htmlsingle/#startup.retrieving.drain):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v3+json
Content-Length: 847

{
  "springBootVersion" : "2.5.4",
  "timeline" : {
    "startTime" : "2021-08-19T11:49:23.227Z",
    "events" : [ {
      "endTime" : "2021-08-19T11:49:23.366Z",
      "duration" : "PT0.001S",
      "startupStep" : {
        "name" : "spring.beans.instantiate",
        "id" : 1,
        "tags" : [ {
          "key" : "beanName",
          "value" : "homeController"
        } ],
        "parentId" : 0
      },
      "startTime" : "2021-08-19T11:49:23.365Z"
    }, {
      "endTime" : "2021-08-19T11:49:23.366Z",
      "duration" : "PT0.003S",
      "startupStep" : {
        "name" : "spring.boot.application.starting",
        "id" : 0,
        "tags" : [ {
          "key" : "mainApplicationClass",
          "value" : "com.example.startup.StartupApplication"
        } ]
      },
      "startTime" : "2021-08-19T11:49:23.363Z"
    } ]
  }
}
```

## QUESTION

why the timestamps are different？what should i do to get the right response with proper timestamp format?

Comment: I don't know if it's related, but note that in the docs they used spring boot 3. Please compare apples with apples and look for the relevant docs for your versions

Comment: @MorBlau my mistake. Now i have found the relevant docs and edited my question.

Comment: The spring boot actuator is still using v3 in your example: `Content-Type: application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v3+json`. Try to find your version, it's very possible this is the issue

Comment: @MorBlau the version is the same as the official docs.

Comment: somewhere LocalDateTime is being serialized

Comment: update to sping-boot v2.6.x fix the problem, but don't konw why.